# CHARINDEX("(",ColumnName)-1) errors

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I'm trying to clean a column data by deleting what comes after the open parentheses:

`LEFT(columnName, CHARINDEX("(",columnName)-1) as columnName`

But I keep getting this error:

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: An unmatched parenthesis occurs in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the feeling, its SFMC Query validator being 'helpful' and reading your string (*which by the way, you should be using (`'`) single quotes, not (`"`) double quotes*) as if it were a parenthesis to be checked. Which is very annoying.

What you can do to get around these overzealous validations is use the `CHAR()` funtion to have the SQL fill in that char without explicitly writing it. E.g. `(` = `CHAR(40)`.

So for instance:

```sql
SELECT SubscriberKey,
LEFT(columnName, CHARINDEX(CHAR(40),columnName)-1) as columnName
FROM [test_charIndex]
```

Should do the trick.  For example on my test data set of:

```
SubscriberKey  |  columnName
8675309        |  my name (is cool)
```

It returned:

```
SubscriberKey  |  columnName
8675309        |  my name
```